# How to get object from ArrayObgect in php?

Tags: php, class, object, arrayobject

i have problem ! 
I had just started working with php , but i understand all , but one thing i try understand , but can't...(
So the problem is this - I create a class, for example, this:

```
class User{
public $name;
public $password;

public function getPassword()
{
return $this->password;
}

public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
}
```

When I try to create an array of objects of this class, pre-filled with data objects:

```
 {
 $arrayUsers = new ArrayObject();

 $user1 = new User();
 $user1->name="lol";
 $user1->password=9898898;

 $user2 = new User();
 $user2->name="lal";
 $user2->password=988;


 $user3 = new User();
 $user3->name="lRus";
 $user3->password=1;


 $arrayUsers->append(array($user1,$user2,$user3));
 }
```

And after trying to get the object (User class) back from the array, then it does not work ... (Tried many ways, just tried array class)
So I have two questions:
1. How to get out of this array is the object class user?
1.1 In this case, the object functions continue to operate. For example :

```
 $obtainedObject_parentClass_is_User->getName();
 //Log : "lol"
```

2. If the answer to the previous question is not possible, then how to implement an array where you can get the object, after which you can use?
For example like this:

```
 $obtainedObject_parentClass_is_User->getName();
 //Log : "lol"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confused between the PHP class **ArrayObject** and **an array of objects**.

You can declare your array of objects in one statement like,

```
$users = [
    'user_1' => new User(),
    'user_2' => new User(),
    'user_3' => new User()
];
```

You can then assign the properties like,

```
$users['user_1']->name = 'Barry';
$users['user_1']->password = 'superSecret';
/// etc...
```

Then to retreive the data,

```
echo $users['user_1']->getName(); // returns Barry
```